# Erro desconhecido no gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, npm

Adicionei o arquivo `mixins.sass` ao meu projeto e quando fui olhar no terminal, apresentou o seguinte erro:

> events.js:160 er; // Unhandled 'error' event 
>    Error: sass\molecules\mixins.sass 
>    Error: no mixin named css3-prefix 
>    Backtrace: 
>       sass/molecules/mixins.sass:69 
>       on line 69 of sass/molecules/mixins.sass 
>       @include css3-prefix('column-gap', $gap); 
>   
>       at options.error (C:\Users\loja\Desktop\Alacarte\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)`

Não Faço ideia o que seja agora toda hora que dou o comando `gulp` aparece esse *log*, já verifiquei o arquivo especificado e não encontrei nada de errado.

Comment: o erro aponta para a linha 69 do arquivo, provavelmente está tentando executar o include porém não o encontra. Dê uma olhada nisso.

Comment: `Linha 67 =columns($count: 3, $gap: 10) 
 Linha 68 @include css3-prefix('column-count', $count)
 Linha 69 @include css3-prefix('column-gap', $gap)` 
 

esse a linha que ele esta monstrando, não há erro

Comment: `Error: no mixin named css3-prefix` não existe um mixin com o nome `css3-prefix`. Verifique se não há erro de digitação.